# how to make the events work for the list inside the fieldset which is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css

**
How to make the 'li' tag work with the javascript events which is inside the fieldset(disabled). I don't know why it is not working please help with this.
**

```js
const enabledButton = document.querySelector('.file-download');

enabledButton.addEventListener('click', () => alert("ok"));
```

```css
.file-displayer {
  padding-left: 5px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.file-download {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 12px;
}

[role="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  cursor: default;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<fieldset disabled>
  <label id="77">&nbsp;Supporting documents</label><br id="78"><button id="79" type="button" class="w3-button w3-indigo w3-border w3-round-large" style="margin-top: 3px;">&nbsp;Attach</button><input id="80" name="supdoc" type="file" required="true" accept="*"
    style="display: none;">
  <ul id="81" name="supdoc_displayer" class="file-displayer" style="width: 100%;"><span><i class="fa fa-minus-square w3-left" title="delete" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red; cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i><span class="sr-only">delete</span>
    <li class="file-download" role="button" tabindex="0" title="download">roles.PNG</li>
    </span>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: If a parent is disabled, the children will be disabled.....

Comment: Set the fieldset's disabled property to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add  `pointer-events:auto!important;`to `.file-download` class will work. if you use dev console without add pointer event you will see is disabled how parent.

```js
const enabledButton = document.querySelector('.file-download');

enabledButton.addEventListener('click', () => alert("ok"));
```

```css
.file-displayer {
padding-left: 5px;
max-height: 50px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: auto;
}

.file-download {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 12px;
    pointer-events:auto!important;
}

[role="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  cursor: default;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<fieldset disabled>
  <label id="77">&nbsp;Supporting documents</label><br id="78"><button id="79" type="button" class="w3-button w3-indigo w3-border w3-round-large" style="margin-top: 3px;">&nbsp;Attach</button>
  <input id="80" name="supdoc" type="file" required="true" accept="*" style="display: none;">
  
  <ul id="81" name="supdoc_displayer" class="file-displayer" style="width: 100%;"><span><i class="fa fa-minus-square w3-left"  title="delete" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red; cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i><span class="sr-only">delete</span><li class="file-download" role="button"
    tabindex="0" title="download">roles.PNG</li></span></ul>
    
  </fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: You are welcome :) please upvote and acept my answer.

Comment: @shivaan can you flag answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

To suggest an alternative answer...

Get rid of the disabled tag and disable it via Javascript. Assign an ID to the fieldset and the list you wish to keep enabled. Then in JS on page load or similar event, disable the fieldset and then enable the list.

I think this is an easier and more effective solution. As it's specifically only the li. The - for removing the entry is still independant and disabled.

So you can click it and nothing happens. (Currently)
Rather than clicking it and getting the alert as if it's part of the list!

See the below Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form :input').prop('disabled', true);
    $("#btn1").prop('disabled', false);
})
        

const enabledButton = document.querySelector('.file-download');

enabledButton.addEventListener('click', () => alert("ok"));
```

```css
.file-displayer {
padding-left: 5px;
max-height: 50px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: auto;
}

.file-download {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 12px;
}

[role="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  cursor: default;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<fieldset id="form">
  <label id="77">&nbsp;Supporting documents</label><br id="78"><button id="79" type="button" class="w3-button w3-indigo w3-border w3-round-large" style="margin-top: 3px;">&nbsp;Attach</button>
  <input id="80" name="supdoc" type="file" required="true" accept="*" style="display: none;">
  <ul id="81" name="supdoc_displayer" class="file-displayer" style="width: 100%;">
    <span><i class="fa fa-minus-square w3-left" title="delete" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red; cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i><span class="sr-only">delete</span>
      <li id="btn1" class="file-download" role="button" tabindex="0" title="download">roles.PNG</li>
    </span>
  </ul>
  </fieldset>
</body>
```